# how to display search bar on top of UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ipad

How to display search bar has shown in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in view add searchbar then add uitableview below on it.its simple use IB.

first add searchbar then add tableview.otherwise u will be add them in tableview headerview which will scroll with tableview.be careful